# Html Search Table

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have this Javascript code:

```
<script>
    var $rows = $('#table tbody tr');
    $('#search').keyup(function() {

        var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
                reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
                text;

        $rows.show().filter(function() {
            text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
            return !reg.test(text);
        }).hide();
    });
</script>
```

I need to make one modification to it that will do this:

I need to make it so it only searches through the 2nd and 9th column.

What do I need to do for this?

Comment: first of all, please post your html too. even if the html is irrelevant for the question, sometimes there can be a small mistake in the html which will prevent the code from working. second - have you tried solving it yourself first? dropping off a code with requirements is not how this website works. please show your failed attempts, and we will help you correct them. third - you need it to search **only in 2nd and 9th columns** ? or **2nd through 9th** ?

Comment: @Banana 2nd AND 9th.

Answer (score 0):

Don't filter on the entire column, just the 2ns and 9th columns for only the 2nd and 9th columns

```
var $rows = $('#table tbody tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {

    var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
            reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
            text;

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var isMatch;
        var secondCol = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)');
        var ninthCol = $(this).find('td:nth-child(9)');
        return !reg.test(secondCol) && !erg.test(ninthCol);
    }).hide();
});
```